# Parse JSON response from api and filter results

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

hello guys I'm pretty new to the field so sorry about the ignorance
im trying to make a function that sending http post requests >> get json response >> take only 'expiresdate' value and save into variable to use it later.

i try to do something like this:

```
def getexpiresdate():
    lastdiclist = getSettingsFromFile()
    WhoApi = lastdiclist['wxakey']
    url = f'https://www.whoisxmlapi.com/whoisserver/WhoisService?'
    apiurl = f'{url}apiKey={WhoApi}&domainName={askfordomain()}'
    r = requests.get(apiurl).json()
    results = r.json()
    print(results)

getexpiresdate()
```

and i get some erros:

```
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

I would love if someone would help me understand how i parsing the json and extract only one value.

Answer (score 2):

First, check if the URL returns correct JSON.
Second, you're converting to JSON twice. Either use:

```
r = requests.get(apiurl)
results = r.json()
```

or

```
results = requests.get(apiurl).json()
```

Comment: im getting  error while trying this...   raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Comment: using postman or curl , send request to

`https://www.whoisxmlapi.com/whoisserver/WhoisService?apiKey=XXXXX&domainName=YYYY`

what result are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

I think your json is invalid. Based on the code posted, you have called twice the json(). So your correct code should be some how like this:

```
import requests

response = requests.get(API_URL)
print(response.json())
```

You can use IP2WHOIS to get the WHOIS result. For example,

```
import requests

response = requests.get('https://api.ip2whois.com/v2?key=YOUR_API_KEY&domain=domain_name&format=json')
print(response.json())
```